# MS Access SQL query counting values in more than one column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having an issue that basically invovles an SQL query in MS Access counting criteria from multiple fields. The data I am working with is as follows:-

```
Option 1     Option 2    Option 3
abc          def          ghi
abc          ghi          def
def          abc          jkl
```

And how I want the query to display my data:

```
abc - 3
def - 3
ghi - 2
jkl - 1
```

Forgive me if this is quite a basic question. I didn't know how best to put into words the nature of my enquiry and I am relatively new to SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a non normalized database :-(

Comment: Yeah the data itself is in a horrible format, it's the car order configuration data history from a manufacturer that we have to do some analysis on. 

Hansup - if the next row contains another instance of abc then the count should be 4 yes, if however abc was not present in row 4 then the count should be 3. I am attempting to count each instance of abc when it appears anywhere in a row essentially.

Comment: Hansup - Each time a option code (such as abc) appears in a record it can only occur once in that record as it is a unique identifier for one of the car's options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OPTION,sum(count) from (
  SELECT OPTION1 as OPTION,COUNT(*) as count FROM Table GROUP BY OPTION1
  union all
  SELECT OPTION2,COUNT(*) as count FROM Table GROUP BY OPTION2
  union all
  SELECT OPTION3,COUNT(*) as count FROM Table GROUP BY OPTION3
)group by OPTION
```

This should do the trick, not sure if that is the correct syntax but just adjust it.

Its a two steps query, first - count for each column grouping by their name. And second - sum the total unioning all the results

Comment: Thanks Sagi, this essentially allowed me to do what I wanted :)